# Set Association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I used a migration in ruby to create these tables together with a model.

I have a Table Information and a Table Detail, each entry in the information table can have one association in the detail table.

So i created them with:

```
create_table :details do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :Bezeichnung
      t.binary :Koordinaten
    end

 create_table :informations do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.integer :DetailID
      t.integer :Longitude
      t.integer :Latitude
    end
```

In my Information Table i got a DetailID which should Reference to the id of the Detail table.

Now i did:

```
ALTER TABLE informations
      ADD CONSTRAINT fk_informations_details
      FOREIGN KEY (DetailID)
      REFERENCES details(id)
```

Is this correct? Have i set the FOREIGN KEY correct? Or do i have to put the foreign key in the other table!?

Because i want to use in my Information Model following:

```
has_one :detail, :foreign_key => 'DetailID'
```

And in the Detail Model following:

```
belongs_to :main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Perform all kinds of alterations on the database using migrations, never do them by hand.
2. Use Ruby on Rails naming convention whenever possible. This means using `detail_id` instead of `DetailID`
3. Your associations are wrong.

If `Information has_one :detail`, Ruby on Rails will look for an entity with a matching `information_id` in the `details` table.

In your model, it is the other way around - the `Information` contains a `detail_id`. In other words Ruby on Rails would specify this as `Information belongs_to :detail` and `Detail has_one :information`.

Comment: Thank you!

So, but the foreign key in the information table is set correctly right?

Do i have to specify the foreign key in this line too? 
belongs_to :detail, foreign_key => 'detail_id'

Comment: If you follow rails' convention, you do not have to manually supply the foreign key.